# <a> tag showing as a different size on chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My issue is with this code here, you can view it at lapismc.net. for whatever reason it displays differently in chrome than it does in Firefox.

The "w-" classes are from CandyUI.css.
The popup-button classes are below.

```css
.popup {
    height: 170px;
    min-height: 170px;
    background-color: #244753;
    border-top: 5px black;
    box-shadow: black 0 -1px 3px 0, black 0 1px 3px 0;
    }

    .popup-container {
    height: 120px;
    }

    .popup-para {
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    }

    .popup-button {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .popup-button.youtube {
    background-color: #5069ed;
    }

    .popup-button.youtube:hover {
    background-color: #4259c0;
    }

    .popup-button.facebook {
    background-color: #3973ed;
    }

    .popup-button.facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3062ce;
    }

    .popup-button.forums:hover {
    background-color: #2776bb;
    }
```

```html
<div class="w-section w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny popup">
        <div class="w-container popup-container">
            <h1 class="heading white popup-title">Keep Updated</h1>
            <p class="popup-para">Check out our Media Portals</p>
            <a href="https://lapismc.net/facebook" class="w-button popup-button facebook">Visit our Facebook Page</a>
            <a href="mailto:contact@lapismc.net" class="w-button popup-button youtube">Send us an Email</a>
            <a href="https://lapismc.net/discord" target="_newtab" class="w-button popup-button forums">Join our Discord Server</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The buttons display like this in chrome

[image: chrome]

and like this in firefox and edge

[image: others]

Any and all help is appreciated, please keep in mind that I am primarily a Java developer and have limited knowledge of CSS. Thanks.

Comment: The best thing you could do is create a [mcve] in the question, making sure the problem is reproduced. This way we could inspect and tell you exactly what code you need. Note the code you posted [does not reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/rze6eskw/) the problem.

Comment: I don't see that specific difference in the browsers. I do see various other differences though.

Comment: i advice you to check the HTML, sometimes a bad syntax can break things, it can be not related to CSS. And of course you need to consider all the CSS not only a part of it

Comment: update your question with the candyUI.css. It's needed to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the three buttons and use flexbox. I'd also make them full-width on narrow devices. Here's an example. It's a proof of concept. If you need help applying it to your code, consider adding a live snippet to your question, reproducing the problem.

```css
.popup {
  height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background-color: #244753;
  border-top: 5px black;
  box-shadow: black 0 -1px 3px 0, black 0 1px 3px 0;
  display: inlin-block;
}

.popup-container {
  height: 120px;
}

.popup-para {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.popup-button {
  margin: 0 0 7px 7px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup-button.youtube {
  background-color: #5069ed;
}

.popup-button.youtube:hover {
  background-color: #4259c0;
}

.popup-button.facebook {
  background-color: #3973ed;
}

.popup-button.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3062ce;
}

.popup-button.forums {
  background-color: #3585ee;
}

.popup-button.forums:hover {
  background-color: #2776bb;
}
.button-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #244753;
  padding: 7px 7px 0 0;
}
.button-bar > * {
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.33% - 7px);
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .button-bar {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .button-bar > * {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    max-width: calc(100% - 7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w-section w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny popup">
  <div class="w-container popup-container">
    <h1 class="heading white popup-title">Keep Updated</h1>
    <p class="popup-para">Check out our Media Portals</p>
    <div class="button-bar">
      <a href="https://lapismc.net/facebook" class="w-button popup-button facebook">Visit our Facebook Page</a>
      <a href="mailto:contact@lapismc.net" class="w-button popup-button youtube">Send us an Email</a>
      <a href="https://lapismc.net/discord" target="_newtab" class="w-button popup-button forums">Join our Discord Server</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```